# Javascript - Pop up / Slider involving dates

Tags: javascript, php

So I'm trying to implement a little feature on one of my web pages.

When the user is registering, they must put in their DOB. What i want to do with this date is that the page should read the date (as soon as it is entered) and if the user registering is over 18, another little thing drops down underneath it asking a whether they have a Bar Manager's Licence

I'm not too sure how to do this, so any help that could be provided would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use 3 combo boxes normally, but just to give you a quick working example see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EU8nF/)

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="iDOB" name="iDOB" onblur="checkAge('iDOB');" /> e.g "01/01/1980"
<div id='dropdown'>
<Label>Licence</Label>
<select>
    <option value="no">no</option>
    <option value="yes">yes</option>
</select>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){$('#dropdown').hide();})

function checkAge(textbox) {
    var textInput = document.getElementById(textbox).value;

    //Turns dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd
    var Bdate = new Date(textInput.replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/,'$3-$2-$1'));    
    var Cdate = new Date();

    //turns differance in dates from milliseconds to years
    var age = Math.floor( ( (Cdate - Bdate) / 1000 / (60 * 60 * 24) ) / 365.25 );

    if (age >= 18){
        // if 18 or older show combobox
        $("#dropdown").show();
    }            
    else
    {
        //else hide it
        $("#dropdown").hide();
    }
}
```

Regards

Adam

Answer (score 0):

Normally I wouldn't go for this type of thing but here take a look at this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oueasley/x8m4G/)**

Basically just take use the

```
getAge(dateString)
```

to get the age and then if it's over 18 it will trigger

```
$("#dropdown").slideToggle();
```